# Trying to Implement Move Constructor to replace Copy Constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I was wondering if someone could look at the following code and tell me where I'm going wrong. The error message I'm getting is:

> C2280 attempting to reference a deleted function

I'm trying to implement a "Move Constructor" that will be better than the regular Copy Constructor. If anyone could help me I will be eternally grateful! Thanks in advance!

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <iostream>
struct Item
{
    //Item attributes
    std::string sItemName;
    double *dSalePrice;
    int *iQuantitySold;
    
    //Constructor which uses initalisation list to create true initalization, as opposed to initalising in the body of the constructor which isn't true initalisation.
    Item(std::string sInitItemName, double dInitSalePrice, int iInitQuantitySold) //initalisation list
    {
        sItemName = sInitItemName;
        dSalePrice = new double;
        iQuantitySold = new int;

        *dSalePrice = dInitSalePrice;
        *iQuantitySold = iInitQuantitySold;
    }
    Item(const Item& objSource)
        :Item(objSource.sItemName, *objSource.dSalePrice, *objSource.iQuantitySold)
    {

        std::cout << "The copy constructor is being called.\n";

    }
//Problems occur when implementing this function here
    Item(Item&& objSource) noexcept
        :sItemName(objSource.sItemName),dSalePrice(objSource.dSalePrice), iQuantitySold(objSource.iQuantitySold)
    {
        
        objSource.dSalePrice = nullptr;
        objSource.iQuantitySold = nullptr;
    }
    ~Item() {
        delete dSalePrice;
        delete iQuantitySold;
    }

};

int main(){
std::vector<Item>vecOfItems;
Item newItem("New Item",32.23,43);
vecOfItems.push_back(newItem);
}
```

Comment: On what line? Can you simplify this to a [mcve] please? There's loads of stuff here that surely has nothing to do with the move ctor error.

Comment: Also, this builds for me ([demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a6e4ae77ed3479c5)).

Comment: Finally, your comment on the ctor is ironic, because you're _not_ using the ctor-initialiser-list — you _are_ assigning in the body, which is what you're claiming not to do.

Comment: Can you elaborate please on that last comment. Also I've improved it by giving a running example and commented where the error is occuring.

Comment: Your move construtor copy assigns `sItemName` rather than moving.  That copy won't cause a bug, but is needlessly slow.

Comment: It still [builds for me](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6e1699458b5b7fb).

Comment: Your question has half of an error message, but we need the full error message to answer this fully.  If you're using VIsual Studio, the full error can be found in the output window, _not_ the error window.

Comment: ... and [works, as long as I put a `std::move` in to trigger it](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/baa27bd2f50f705c).

Comment: Error C2280 'Item &Item::operator =(const Item &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio on Windows 10.

Comment: How would I move the std::string?

Comment: [Visual C++ 19.24 builds it too](https://godbolt.org/z/zfqnXw). But try following the comments above — you have not provided any assignment operators (and the vector will want these internally when you do more complex operations).

Comment: As for moving the string .. the same way you move anything else! `std::move`. e.g. `:Item(std::move(objSource.sItemName), *objSource.dSalePrice, *objSource.iQuantitySold)`

Comment: https://github.com/WS239618/Business-Sales-Calculator

Comment: That's a link to my GitHub.

Comment: Okay. I understand. I haven't advanced yet to start overloading the operators. Could you give an example of how I could apply that in the code?

Comment: There are loads of examples online and there should be some in your book too.